# Laptop broke down when Deep Freeze is still active, Cannot start Windows in another laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bsod, deep-freeze

I am using Deep Freeze Standard v8 in Windows 7. One day my computer won't start at all due to mainboard failure. It is totally dead. The problem is that Deep Freeze was active when it happened. I have to move my harddisk to a new laptop. Unfortunately it is a new laptop with different specs than the broken one. I keep getting BSOD in the new laptop. What can I do?

Comment: any helpful info in the BSOD?

Comment: STOP: 0x0000007B (0XFFFFF880009AE7E8, 0xFFFFFFFFC0000034, 0x0000000000000000x 0x0000000000000000)

Comment: I tried to launch Startup Repair to no avail with a message like .... Bad Driver

Answer (score 0):

You can't just move a old hard drive to a new computer, as the windows drivers/files will be made for the old computer.

The easiest way to fix this is to install (or reinstall) windows on the hard drive that came with the new computer,
then move the data from, let's say `[OldDrive]/Users/[YourOldUserName]/Documents/`

to `C:/Users/[YourNewUserName]/Documents/`.

That's how you do it for `Documents`, but if you want to do it for `Pictures` or anything else, you just find that directory, and copy (or move) the files to the new computer's hard drive.